# Filtering plots in power BI on through column names

Tags: powerbi, visualization, unpivot

I have the following tables

[image: Data on energy consumption]

I have several tables on coal consumption, natural gas, .....

I want to have a power BI model that can allow viewing these data with years (x-axis) while filtering on countries.

I have transposed the data to have a column with years and countries on the columns. But I cannot filter on countries.

Another thing I have done is to unpivot all the data and have four columns (country, year, value, fuel type) but the problem is that I could not manage to create suitable relationships between the tables as there is no primary key.

I have thought on putting all the data fro the different energy sources in one table. But how can I manage to link it to more data per country at year as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Another thing I have done is to unpivot all the data and have four columns (country, year, value, fuel type)

This is totally the right approach.

The next step required in minimum is to combine all unpivotted tables vertically into one EnergyConsumption table. You can utilize **Append Queries** command in Power Query Editor, or **Table.Combine** function in M language.

Additionally, you should consider to create three tables: Years, Countries, and FuelTypes, which have unique values of the respective dimensions, and establish one to many relationship with EnergyConsumption table.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
One more question please, what should I add in the year table for example, just the years in the table as one column